Jquery Datatable - pagination not working
I'm working on Visual Studio .Net core MVC project. Datatable Pagination Show entries dropdown is getting displayed but all the records is getting displayed. After the initial page load, when the dropdown selection is clicked, no data is showing up.
Previous Next buttons is getting displayed in the bottom of the datatable but the buttons are disabled.
Am I missing a datatable property?  Thanks in advance!!
Since the data is fetched as ajax post, I tried setting serverside:false on the datatable. But this did not fix the issue.
$(window).on('load', function () {
   $('#tblMortTrans').DataTable({
      destroy: true,
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": false,
      "autowidth": false,
      "info": false,
      "lengthChange": true,
      "searching": false,
      async: false,
      "paging": true,
      "pageLength": 10,
      "lengthMenu": ["10", "25", "All"],
      "order": [], 
      "language": ""
   });
})


$('#btnFind').click(function () {
   $.ajax({

      url: obj.RestUrl,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      headers: {
         'appName': obj.appName
      },
      type: "POST",
      data: JSON.stringify(
         {
            accountNumber: $("#txtAcnt").val(),
            accountType: $('#selAccountType').val()
         }),
      datatype: "json",
      success: function (data, msg) {
         getRestData(data); 
      }
   });
}

